# Is it possible to convert an at runtime unknown Avro message into a specific Java class

Tags: java, spring, avro, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm looking into Avro as a serialization format to publish events in a Java application.

**What I'd like to do is convert some Avro bytes into an instance of a specific Java class, which I generated using the Avro Maven plugin, and vice versa.**

I'd like to do this because it would allow the developers using my code to subscribe to a specific event and receive an instance of the specific generated class representing that specific event (maybe casting it to the Event class from an Object, but not having to touch any Avro specific code).

I can do this in a specific way, by writing code using the [SpecificDatumReader](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/specific/SpecificDatumReader.html) and passing in the generated class to specify which class I expect. Unfortunately, this would require writing code for every generated class. An alternative would be using the [GenericDatumReader](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericDatumReader.html), but this wouldn't give me an instance of the generated class I would want. I think I want something in between these two solutions, get a specific object as the output but have the flexibility of the generic approach.

I'm thinking of a solution in which I check the schema of the serialized message and create a SpecificDatumReader for this, which in turn creates the instance of the generated class.

**Is this at all possible? How would I go about this? Any help is appreciated!**

*Some more specific contextual information: I'm publishing and subscribing to these events using RabbitMQ in a Spring application. Spring offers a [RabbitTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html) for easy use of RabbitMQ and this class allows you to set a [MessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#setMessageConverter-org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter-). What I'd like to do is create a generic MessageConverter which uses the Avro schema I created to turn bytes into a number of possible Java objects (generated by the Maven plugin) and Java objects into bytes. The latter (objects to bytes) sounds doable but I have no idea how to go about the former (bytes to objects).*

***Update December 29th 2016***: None of the suggested solutions worked for us. Eventually we stepped away from Avro and went for a completely different solution. Therefore, I won't accept the suggested answer as it didn't help me and I can't vouch for its correctness.

Comment: please don't just ask us. try it yourself.

Comment: @PhilippSander hi Philipp, I am trying but I'm stuck because I can't find an API which seems to enable this functionality. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, I'm not asking anyone to write this code for me .

Answer (score 0):

There's no Avro API to get the record type from an Avro binary encoding because the Avro binary encoding does not have that data. A record is encoded by encoding the values of its fields in the order that they are declared. In other words, a record is encoded as just the concatenation of the encodings of its fields. Field values are encoded per their schema. That's why Avro must be provided the schema originally used to encode the data in order to decode it.

Because the bytes output by Avro's binary encoding don't specify the record type, you must send the record type along side Avro's binary encoded data. Change the messages sent to RabbitMQ to be a composition of (1) the schema used to encode the data and (2) the Avro binary encoded data. If you don't what to blow up the message size by including the schema, you can include an identifier for the schema instead. The consumer program would retrieve the schema by that identifier from a [schema registry](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/index.html). A custom [MessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/MessageConverter.html) can extract the schema from the message to see which of the many record types is in the message.

Comment: Thanks @chin-huang! I know that, I was just wondering whether it is possible to see which of the many record types in my protocol the message is, so I can create the appropriate (generated) class instance for it. Do you know if that's possible in the Java API?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @chin-huang! You're helping me better rephrase the question . Do you know if it is possible with the Java API to get this schema and apply it to a SpecificDatumReader for example?

Comment: @tan9 that looks interesting, I'm going to look into that.